# Issue computing difference between two csv files

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to obtain the difference between two csv files A.csv and B.csv in order to obtain new rows added in the second file. A.csv has the following data.

```
acct    ABC     88888888    99999999    ABC-GHD 4/1/18  4   1   2018    Redundant/RSK
```

B.csv has the following data.

```
acct    ABC     88888888    99999999    ABC-GHD 4/1/18  4   1   2018    Redundant/RSK
acct    ABC     88888888    99999999    ABC-GHD 4/1/18  4   1   2018    DT/89
```

To write the new rows added into an output file I'm using the following script.

```
input_file1 = "A.csv"
input_file2 = "B.csv"
output_path = "out.csv"

with open(input_file1, 'r') as t1:
    fileone = set(t1)
with open(input_file2, 'r') as t2, open(output_path, 'w') as outFile:
    for line in t2:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

Expected output is :

```
acct    ABC     88888888    99999999    ABC-GHD 4/1/18  4   1   2018    DT/89
```

Output obtained through the above script is :

```
acct    ABC     88888888    99999999    ABC-GHD 4/1/18  4   1   2018    Redundant/RSK
acct    ABC     88888888    99999999    ABC-GHD 4/1/18  4   1   2018    DT/89
```

I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake, tried debugging it but with no progress.

Comment: Your first file does not have a trailing newline. `'...' != '...\n'`

Comment: Thanks for identifying the issue Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful with trailing newlines. As such it is safer to remove the newlines before comparing and then add them back when writing:

```
input_file1 = "A.csv"
input_file2 = "B.csv"
output_path = "out.csv"

with open(input_file1, 'r') as t1:
    fileone = set(t1.read().splitlines())

with open(input_file2, 'r') as t2, open(output_path, 'w') as outFile:
    for line in t2:
        line = line.strip()

        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line + '\n')
```